# preg_replace for changing sql query string

Tags: sqlite, preg-replace

I have problems with sqlite3 and "num_rows". I cannot ask for num_rows of a result like mysql.Now i wan't to automate my SELECT query to ask for the rowcount.
Is there a way to replace all between two patterns?

Like

```
    SELECT date,name,etc FROM myTable WHERE gender=1
// to
SELECT count(*) FROM myTable WHERE gender=1
```

I must replace all between SELECT and FROM with count(*).
Can i do this this preg_replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example provided it's simple, but I guess it won't work for all query syntaxes. But have it a try:

PHP code (don't know language you do use):

```
$count_sql = preg_replace('/^(SELECT)\\s+.*?\\s+(FROM.*)$/s', '$1 count(*) $2', $select_sql);
```

But I guess, there is a more elegant way to find the `num_rows` thing. You could use a subquery, like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ( *** original query here *** )
```

It's not very efficient, but you don't have to deal with the query syntax.

Comment: Thanks plenty for that more elegant way! I had no idea that worked and had been pulling hair out of my head for a while now.